# Is faces-config.xml file automcatically create?

Tags: netbeans, jsf-2, faces-config

I tried to create simple JSF facelet project in Netbeans IDE.

I did the following steps in Netbeans.

Select framework - Java Server faces
Registered libraries is JSF2.0
Preferred Language is facelet.

I am not able to find the faces-config.xml file under WEB-INF in netbeans IDE.
Do i need to create faces-config.xml file manually, or netbeans IDE will generate automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSF 2.0 doesn't require faces-config.xml. I don't have Netbeans installed now but if you want it to create faces-config.xml for you, you should try: `New file -> JSF -> JSF Faces config`.